# Use multiple Camera on Instagram Live

Tags: camera, instagram, live-streaming

I use my Android Phone and I want to use  multiple camera on Instagram live video  and switch between. I have 2 question:

1. How I can do this?
2. Can I use windows to send live stream as Instagram live?

Please help me, thank you

Comment: are you taking about instagram api

Comment: No about android app